# Google Maps API fastest route

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

This is my code for the map.
But when you run it, everything is fine at first. Then if you click the "Let's Go!" you get this error:
`Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object; and not an ObjectAb @ maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/11a/main.js:16
index.html:7`
and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'N' of null
```

Does anyone know how to fix this??? If so please help

html:

```
<div id="floating-panel">
   <input id="toAddress" type="textbox" value="">
   <input id="submit" type="button" value="Lets Go!">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

javascript:

```
        var currentPosition;

        function initMap() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: {lat: 33.8, lng: -84.4}

          });
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

          var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
          trafficLayer.setMap(map);

          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
          var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

          if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
              };

              currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(pos.geolocation.lat), parseFloat(pos.geolocation.lng));


              infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
              infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
              map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function() {
              handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
          } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          }
        }

        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
          infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
          infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        }
          document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
            // geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

            directionsService.route({
                origin: currentPosition,
                destination: document.getElementById('toAddress').value,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
              }, function(response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                } else {
                  window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                }
              });

          });



        function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
          var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
          geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
              });
            } else {
              alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
          });

        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. There is no HTML ("Let's Go") button in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the lat and lng coordinates are not in the proper format `in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object; and not an ObjectAb` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'N' of null` means one of your values is entering your function as null or nothing. Post some of your HTML if you can. If you don`t want to.. I would console.log what this destination value is before this code gets run.

```
 directionsService.route({
            origin: currentPosition,    //<------
            destination: document.getElementById('toAddress').value,  //<------
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
              window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
          });
```

Also check what the current position value being returned is could be that your geolocator is turned off. If it was it would explain the cannot read property 'N' of null error you are getting.

It's probably not the answer you were looking for but maybe this will help with some debugging. Post a simplified version of your html as well.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This error will come when your `navigator.geolocation` fails, in that case you will not have `currentPosition` set with a latlng literal so the direction `API`  will give error since origin is `unknown`.